# Extract specific types only with no extras allowed

Tags: typescript

I've got a Vue project running TypeScript 5.2.2.

I'm building out a component library at the moment, and many of these components will have some shared properties between each other, which I'd like to simplify the types of rather than having to declare the same exact type dozens or even hundreds of times.

As an example, many of my components have a `size` attribute, which, when brought out to be as generic as possible, looks like this:

```js
type SizeProp = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl';
```

The problem is that not all components will accept all of these as valid properties. A button, for example, could be any of these different options, whereas something like a text input element might only be `sm` or `md`.

What is the best way to type these out, while still getting useful errors within the type itself?

If I try something like below:

```js
type InputProps = {
  size: Extract<SizeProp, 'sm' | 'md' | '2xl'>
}
```

This does technically work, and it will warn me if I try to use the wrong value when implementing this:

```js
const input: InputProps = {
  size: '2xl', // Type "2xl" is not assignable to type "sm" | "md".
};
```

but what I want is for it to also tell me that it's not assignable within the type definition itself, which it currently doesn't (it just silently drops the `2xl`):

```js
type InputProps = {
  size: Extract<SizeProp, 'sm' | 'md' | '2xl'> // It should tell me this is wrong!
}
```

Is there a way of  getting warned when trying to do this?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware - it's basically a union intersection, the output is everything in both unions, but any extras on either side are ignored.

Comment: You can create your own utility: https://tsplay.dev/mb3o3W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make your own helper type for that

```
type ExtractWithCheck<T, U extends T> = Extract<T, U>

type SizeProp = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl';
type InputProps = {
  size: ExtractWithCheck<SizeProp, 'sm' | 'md' | '2xl'>
  //                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Type '"2xl"' is not assignable to type 'SizeProp'.(2344)
}
```

Or you may make your type a generic with default value:

```
type AvailableSizes = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl'
type SizeProp<S extends AvailableSizes = AvailableSizes> = S;

type InputProps = {
  size: SizeProp<'sm' | 'md' | '2xl'>
  //             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Type '"2xl"' is not assignable to type 'AvailableSizes'.(2344)
}
```